# Error in Table caption, several unnecessary line breaks

Tags: tables, captions, indentation

For the below written table code  I get unnecessary line breaks in the caption of the table as shown in the image. How can I get rid of this?

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{graphicx}      % include this line if your document contains figures
\usepackage{natbib}        % required for bibliography
% The following packages can be found on http:\\www.ctan.org
%\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hb]
\begin{center}
\caption{Margin settings}\label{tb:margins}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
Page & Top & Bottom & Left/Right \\\hline
First & 3.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\
Rest & 2.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: unrelated but do not use `epsfig` package, use `graphicx`. `epsfig` is just an emulation package for compatibility with documents written in the 1980s.

Answer (score 1):

The caption package does not work with the class you are using

You get the warning on the terminal and the log

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

Simply remove that package (and `epsfig`)

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you so much. But I dont see the accept answer option!!